What's the byte buddy equivalent of cglib's Enhancer.isEnhanced?
I'm converting some code from cglib to byte buddy.
The current code has this statement:
if (net.sf.cglib.proxy.Factory.class.isAssignableFrom(entityClass) || net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.isEnhanced(entityClass)) {
...
}

Does byte buddy have something equivalent?
Can/should I rely on the class name? (I'm using the default naming strategy)

It does not. Cglib implements an interface for all of its proxies. The method basically checks if an instance is of this interface type. You are free to define your own (marker) interface and check for its implementation.
The disadvantage of cglibs approach is that proxies always need to be loaded by the same class loader as cglib itself. Sometimes, this makes it impossible to use the library.

Would you be open to adding such a marker interface to byte buddy (without every byte buddy enhanced class implementing it by default)? I'm struggling to find a spot in our module structure to put such an interface.

You can add any interface with Byte Buddy. What stops you from adding one?

I'm not sure I'm getting your suggestion.
What I'm saying is:
I have module A with the code from the question. I've added a marker interface "ByteBuddyEnhanced" in A.
I have module B, unrelated to A, where I'm using objects that implement the marker, but I cannot check this since B does not know about A.
I cannot let B depend on A.
I don't have a module both A and B depend on (to put the marker in).
I could add such a module, but a for just one interface this seems silly.
Since both A and B depend on byte-buddy, it makes sense for the marker to be part of byte buddy.

I guess B could check whether the object implements any interface named "ByteBuddyEnhanced", but that feels icky

You'd need to add a common module then, or keep some other form of meta data register.
